# Is jacoco agent required even for offline instrumentation?

Tags: tomcat, jacoco

I have been trying to look at several options for code coverage and am currently looking at Jacoco too.

It supports byte code and does both offline and on-the-fly instrumentation. I am currently exploring the offline instrumentation. But it does look like I will need to run the jacocoagent on the tomcat server, even if I try to do an offline instrumentation, to get a coverage report.

Folks here don't seem to like the jacoco agent running on the tomcat server and have entrusted me to look at other options - like a stand alone agent to collect the coverage data and generate reports based on that [something akin to the EMMA of the earlier times]

Does anyone have a brilliant suggestion on this? [Is it that I am doing something wrong or is there a work around?]

Do note that I am able to generate reports and all that seem fine. Just that I don't want the agent to be running on the tomcat server.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to *run* the JaCoCo agent on the server in the sense that there is some service opening ports or the like. It's just that [offline instrumented classes get a direct dependency on the JaCoCo runtime](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/offline.html), and therefore `jacocoagent.jar` has to be on the classpath. So it's just another library that you build against in case of instrumented builds.